# How to navigate different tabs from controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter.I have a registration form view.Within this view there are several tabs like one for personal details,another for photo upload and another for job details.In first call i load the tab for personal details and there is a submit button for saving personal details.I want to navigate to photo upload tab after i submit the personal data.Is it possible to load photo uploading tab in the same view?

Comment: How can i do that,if you know the way to do this,please help me for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. It Works for me.

View :

```
<?php $tab = (isset($tab)) ? $tab : 'tab1'; ?> 
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
    <li class="<?php echo ($tab == 'tab1') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" > 
        <a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab">Personal Info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($tab == 'tab2') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" > 
        <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab">Family Info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($tab == 'tab3') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" > 
        <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab">Upload Photo</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and for each tab-pane set class as  :

```
<div class="tab-pane <?php echo ($tab == 'tab1') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" id="tab_1_1">
```

Update your controller as:

```
$data['tab'] = 'tab3';

    $this->load->view('commons/header');
    $this->load->view('addmember',$data);
    $this->load->view('commons/footer');
```

Tis code will show 1st tab (Personal info) as the default tab and after submission of 1st tab, it navigate to the 3rd tab (Upload Photo). You can change it to the 2nd tab if needed.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your view looks like.Here is a way that may help you.
First write a function at your controller like this

```
function myFunction($tab=1)//may be index
{
   $data['tab']=$tab;
   //do other stuff
   if($tab==2)
   {
      //save personal details
       $data['id']=the_id_you_saved;
   }
   //suppose your last tab is 3
   if($tab==3)
   {
       //do your stuff or redirect
   }
   $this->load->view('your_tab_view', $data);

}
```

Now your view file will look like this.

```
//load your other htmls
<?php
    if($tab==1)
    {
     ?>
      <form action="controler_name/myFunction/2" method="post">
         //your personal information form
      </form>
     <?php
    }
    else if($tab==2)
    {
    ?>
     <form action="controler_name/myFunction/3" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
         //your file upload form
      </form>
    <?php        
    }
?>
```

Hope you will get the idea how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, though there may be other ways of doing it.

In the view you create three tabs and load the view in each tabs through ajax.
This can be done like when you click submit of the first tab if successful it returns the view for the next tab and on ajax success you display the next tab making the previous tab as display:none;

similarly other tabs. Using [templates](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html) this can be achieved easily.

Comment: I want to save all my data from first tab to database and after the success save i want to navigate to next tab from the controller,is it possible to load from controller?

Comment: yes. use ajax. you can get a complete view inside the controller and give it as the response back and fill the div of tab 2.

Answer (score 0):

`$user['details'] = array('name=>test','email=>test@test.com');
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('addphoto',$user);
$this->load->view('footer');`

> I have give you a sample structure for controller page. From where you can call the add photo and send user details.

Comment: addphoto is not a seperate view,it is a tab within the registration view page